# Python-Finding frequency to perfrom Fourier transform in time series

Tags: python, time-series, fft, similarity

i have a time series over a range of 150000 records. i wanted to perform a Fourier transform to find if there is a similarity in their pattern. My time series feature involves the measurement of a real time System process at each time stamp. Even if there a numerous columns(Features) i wanted to find if there is a repeating pattern. But i dont know a method to find the frequency over the data so that i can perform FFT or DFT.

Comment: Have you checked the scipy.fft package? You can have a look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.3.3/reference/tutorial/fftpack.html

Comment: You said 'i dont know a method to find the frequency over the data so that i can perform FFT or DFT'. You can get frequency content after you do a FFT. So by frequency do you mean the sampling frequency of your time series?

Comment: Yes. I dont have the information regarding the sampling frequency. So i am not sure if i can perform FFT and if it is useful